# Why does my interface fail to extend a union type in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a type which is the union of two interfaces:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
}
interface Bar {
  b: string
}
type Baz = Foo | Bar;
```

I want to extend it, but it gives me an error:

```
interface Qux extends Baz { // error!
  // ---------------> ~~~
  // An interface can only extend an object type or 
  // intersection of object types with statically known members.
  c: string;
}

interface Qux extends Baz { // error!
  c: string;
}
```

Why do I get that error and what can I do about it?

---

Original version of question with more context:

I wrote a type file to augment the `Palette` type defintion file in an npm library. (Material UI to be specific). If I try to have `ODPaletteColorOptions` extend `PaletteColorOptions` as shown in my code below, this does not successfully extend the PaletteColorOptions interface. Here is the outcome: apparently, the ODPaletteColorOptions interface only has the additional keys: [image]

```
createPalette.d.ts
------------------
import { Palette as MuiPalette, PaletteColorOptions } from "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {

    export interface ODPaletteColorOptions extends PaletteColorOptions {
        1000: string,
        white: string,
        black: string,
        0: string,
        Search: string
    }

    export interface Palette extends MuiPalette{
        neutrals: ODPaletteColorOptions,
    };
}
```

Here is the definition of `PaletteColorOptions` from the existing MUI type definition file.

```
export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;
```

where

```
export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
export type ColorPartial = Partial<Color>;
export interface Color {
  50: string;
  100: string;
  200: string;
  300: string;
  400: string;
  500: string;
  600: string;
  700: string;
  800: string;
  900: string;
  A100: string;
  A200: string;
  A400: string;
  A700: string;
}
```

However, if instead of extending PaletteColorOptions, I explicitly extend SimplePaletteColorOptions and ColorPartial, then the extension works.

```
import { Palette as MuiPalette, SimplePaletteColorOptions, ColorPartial } from "@mui/material/styles/createPalette";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {

    export interface ODPaletteColorOptions extends SimplePaletteColorOptions, ColorPartial {
        1000: string,
        white: string,
        black: string,
        0: string,
        Search: string
    }

    export interface Palette extends MuiPalette{
        neutrals: ODPaletteColorOptions,        
    };
}
```

Why does the first approach fail?

Comment: What does "not successfully extend the PaletteColorOptions interface" mean?  What specific problem or error happens?

Comment: Please consider providing a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE.  I'm expecting something like the code demonstrated in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5P1Zw).  If that reproduces your problem I'd be happy to [edit] your question to feature that code instead of the materialui stuff

Comment: @Jcalz That example you provided is exactly what I'm looking for as a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the compiler to process [`interface` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) (as well as instances of [`class` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) which can be seen as having an `interface` of the same name as the class), they need to have *a single set of statically known keys*.  [Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) have multiple sets of keys, so you can't extend them into interfaces.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13604](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604) for a description of what types of things can be extended from (e.g., object types and intersections of such types) as well as some things that cannot be (e.g., generic type parameters).

That's why you would be allowed to extend `Foo` or `Bar` separately, but
not the union `Foo | Bar`.

---

Luckily, you can get much the same effect with [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), as described in [the TS Handbook documentation for differences between type aliases and interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces):

```
type Qux = Baz & { c: string }; // okay
```

Now a `Qux` acts like a `Baz` with a `string`-valued `c` property, which is presumably what you wanted to see:

```
function processQux(q: Qux) {
  console.log(("a" in q ? q.a : q.b).toUpperCase() + " " + q.c);
}

const q: Qux = { a: "hey", c: "you" } // okay
processQux(q) // HEY you
processQux({ b: "it's", c: "me" }) // IT'S me
processQux({ c: "oops" }) // error! 
// Argument of type '{ c: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Qux'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uoksiKAQnFDvsgEYnmUQNemACeABzZwAXsgC8aTMgA+ydlADcuXGMnIAigFcAHvLUzkAMhzIE-CtWS0NyAPSvk6ANZxR23DCGIAhgwOggyOJQ6EikpEbGABQAjiQJAJRcBAjhpOgANhAAdPnoVImJAERwlcigyMnIAPwNRXDIJMlFPOlFYOgAquKSUADCcKQQiZkA1Mi1tXNdCOla9Lg5IOQNaSZm2IQklQAWEKKVADS2R6LohrW0bh7evrhRMRBxCSmZ7sgAEgBRACayFuhje0Vi8RMiQOfHmwDAAHJSJdrvMALYQB6-DwASQAKsiAMrIbGQj5fWEHOzzTDiNFOPHIaDRKAAQmQuD+AEEoFRDNjwJ4YMhdChkbT7IIqC5aMi6qRkCB0GBCHFgFQQHAeIVxVhxBw4NimKLxRJJQlkUVcEA)